# Inner automorphisms of algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-groups

I'm confused about the precise definition of an inner automorphism of an algebraic group. Here is what Milne says in his book on algebraic groups:

Let $k$ be a field, let $\overline{k}$ be an algebraic closure, and let $G$ be an algebraic group over $k$. Let $Z$ (or $Z(G)$) denote the center of $G$. Then an automorphism of $G$ is said to be inner if it becomes of the form inn$(g)$ over $\overline{k}$, where $g \in G(\overline{k})$. The action of $G$ on itself by inner automorphisms, $(x,y) \mapsto xyx^{-1}$, is invariant under $Z(G) \times e$ acting by translation, and so it factors through $G/Z(G)$. The inner automorphisms of $G$ are exactly the automorphisms of $G$ defined by elements of $G/Z(k)$.

I don't understand why we don't simply say that the inner automorphisms of $G$ can be identified with $G/Z$. I think Milne is identifying $G/Z(k)$ with a subset of the underlying topological space $G/Z$.

Comment: I don't have the print copy of Milne to hand, and I can't find this in the last edition of the online notes that he posted.  The point is that $G/Z$ has points valued over all field extensions over $k$ (and more), and, if we want to regard these as inducing automorphisms of $G$ (regarded as a $k$-group), then they had better preserve $G(k)$.  An arbitrary-field-valued point of $G/Z$ doesn't behave this way, but a $k$-valued point $(G/Z)(k)$, which may lift only to a point of $G(\overline k)$, does.  Is that related to your question?

Comment: Inner automorphisms are exactly the $k$-points of $G/Z$, the definition in terms of points over $\bar k$ is just an explanation how the points of the quotient look like.

Comment: @LSpice: Yes. My main confusion is that many papers (say, by Borel) will identify the adjoint group $G^{ad}$ with Inn(G).

Comment: When they make [that identification](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310036/inner-automorphisms-of-algebraic-groups#comment773123_310036), they are regarding $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ as the identity component of the *algebraic* group $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ of *algebraic* automorphisms—that is, in particular, as an algebraic group—whereas Milne is regarding the inner automorphism group as an abstract group (as [@anon](https://mathoverflow.net/users/128701/anon) points out [below](https://mathoverflow.net/a/310220)).

Comment: In particular, Milne's inner automorphism group can change after base change, whereas Borel's can't; and, more precisely, we have $\mathrm{Inn}_{\text{Milne}}(G) = (\mathrm{Inn}_{\text{Borel}}(G))(k)$, or we could perhaps even write more explicitly $\mathrm{Inn}_{\text{Milne}}(G_{/k}) = (\mathrm{Inn}_{\text{Borel}}(G_{/k}))(k)$.

Comment: @LSpice: That clarifies things. Thanks.

Comment: (I should have said, as you do [below](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310036/inner-automorphisms-of-algebraic-groups#comment773158_310220), that regarding $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ as an algebraic group is particular to the semisimple case.  For example, already $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{GL}_1)$ equals $\mathbb Z$—I think that I may say here "as a non-finite-type scheme", but don't rely on me for the right words; anyway it's a discrete topological space—which is not an algebraic group, or even variety, for the silly reason that it has infinitely many components.)

Comment: @LSpice Shouldn't $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{G}_m^n)=\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: @CoffeeBliss, you're right; I was thinking of $\operatorname{End}(\mathrm{GL}_1)$ under pointwise multiplication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inner automorphisms of $G$ form an abstract group, whereas $G/Z$ is an algebraic group (i.e., group scheme of finite type over the field $k$), so you can't say that one is equal to the other --- they are different types of objects. By $(G/Z)(k)$ Milne means the group of $k$-rational points of $G/Z$, which is an abstract group. Each element of $(G/Z)(k)$ defines an automorphism of $G$, and these are exactly the inner automorphisms

Here is the passage in Milne's book 3.51: Let $G$ be an algebraic group over $k$. An automorphism of $G$ is
inner if it becomes of the form $ inn(g)$ over $k^{\mathrm{a}}$. Later
(17.63), we shall see that the group $\mathcal{I}(k)$ of inner
automorphisms of $G$ is equal to $\bar{G}(k)$, where $\bar{G}$ is the quotient
of $G$ by its centre. For example, for $t\in k^{\times}$, the automorphism
$\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)  \mapsto\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
a & tb\\
t^{-1}c & d
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)  $ of $SL_{2}$ is inner because it becomes the inner automorphism
defined by $diag(\sqrt{t},\sqrt{t}\,^{-1})$ over $k^{\mathrm{a}}$. It is also
the inner automorphism defined by the element $diag(t,1)$ of $PGL_{2}(k)$.

Comment: Thanks. In 3.51 I guess Milne regards the set of automorphisms of G as an abstract group. Later he says that if G is semisimple then Aut(G) has an algebraic group structure.